# How can we fix the Azure DevOps SonarQube error: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-devops-server-2019

Since upgrading from SonarQube 7.x to 8, the scans have stopped working. The Build task `Run Code Analysis` seems to succeed with several errors like:

```
Calling the SonarQube Scanner...
INFO: Scanner configuration file: D:\agent6\_work\_tasks\SonarQubePrepare_15b84ca1-b62f-4a2a-a403-89b77a063157\4.8.0\classic-sonar-scanner-msbuild\sonar-scanner-4.1.0.1829\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: D:\agent6\_work\1\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 4.1.0.1829
INFO: Java 1.8.0_181 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Windows Server 2016 10.0 amd64
INFO: User cache: C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\.sonar\cache
INFO: SonarQube server 8.0.0
INFO: Default locale: "en_GB", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
##[error]SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Windows/ServiceProfiles/NetworkService/.sonar/cache/6abbcd30a9bf1fba1794eb6ce16eb36f/scanner-developer-8.0-all.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Windows/ServiceProfiles/NetworkService/.sonar/cache/6abbcd30a9bf1fba1794eb6ce16eb36f/scanner-developer-8.0-all.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
##[error]SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Windows/ServiceProfiles/NetworkService/.sonar/cache/9f2b37948b00b865aaf57dfd335e8d6a/sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-8.0-all.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Windows/ServiceProfiles/NetworkService/.sonar/cache/9f2b37948b00b865aaf57dfd335e8d6a/sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-8.0-all.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
##[error]SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
WARN: SonarScanner will require Java 11+ to run starting in SonarQube 8.x
```

It eventually ends with

```
INFO: SCM writing changed lines (done) | time=172ms 
INFO: Analysis report generated in 1813ms, dir size=2 MB 
INFO: Analysis report compressed in 8453ms, zip size=1 MB 
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 109ms 
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse https://server/sonarqube/dashboard?id=MercuryNew&pullRequest=568 
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report INFO: More about the report processing at https://server/sonarqube/api/ce/task?id=AW7u_AxnikdkBhrYNw3V 
INFO: Analysis total time: 1:19.860 s
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS 
INFO: Total time: 1:21.750s 
INFO: Final Memory: 77M/2590M 
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
The SonarQube Scanner has finished
```

My java version is: "1.8.0_181" and the scanner configuration contains: `wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin\java`

[image]

Has anyone encountered this? Is this a configuration issue or a JAVA version issue? How can I fix the scan errors?

There's another question about this, but in this case I have a brand new install.

Comment: Is the solution here helpful: https://www.baeldung.com/slf4j-classpath-multiple-bindings?

Comment: thank @CeceDong-MSFT it helps to identify the cause of the error, but not sure how to tell SonarQube what dependencies to use (or ignore)

Comment: Same thing here, but Sonar's ignoring it: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings/16021/5

Comment: The solution in the link suggest modify the pom.xml file by adding exclusion in the dependencies, you may try it.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT there’s no pom.xml. It is a .net solution being scanned by SonarQube. It is SonarQube that’s experiencing the error. the pom.xml fix is for Maven projects (JAVA)

Comment: I saw Sonar side provided response https://community.sonarsource.com/t/slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings/16021, you may check it and provide the scanner logs with debug enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Sonarqube:
Deleting the errant `sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-8.0-all.jar` in the lib\scanner folder solved the problem.

[image]